# Understanding output while using flags in printf() in c programming

Tags: c

I was studying about formatted input output functions and found out that i could actually use printf() in a variety of ways, so I started trying out how to use flags in printf() . I was trying to understand # flag , it was stated that if I use it with e,E,f format specifier it "forces the written output to contain a decimal point even if no digits would follow ". So I thought what would happen if i did it with integer but with float formating and also + flag .

```
main()
{
  int  b = 0 , c = 4.53 , d = 3 ;
  float a = 1 ;
  double e = 5.32 ;//please dont mind a,b,c they are remanents from previous testing
  printf("%+#f" , d);    
  return 0 ;
}
```

Output -
-1.#QNAN0

Your Help would be highly appreciated . Thanx in advance for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking undefined behaviour, you can not pass an `int` when `printf` is expecting a `double`.

Variadic functions promotes `float` to `double`, so this works even if `%f` expects a `double`:

```
float f = 3.14;
printf("%f", f);
```

It also promotes `char` and `short int` to `int`:

```
char c = 1;
printf("%d", c);
```

But can not promote an `int` to `double` (as you were expecting), a cast is needed:

```
printf("%+#f", (double)d);
```